# Phonegap CLI - how to update android to 8.0.0 (cordova 9.0.0 CLI)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I reinstall my cordova and phonegap and still have 7.1.1 android version in project.

How to get 8.0.0 android platform?

A lots plugin based on android sdk needs cordova 9.0.0 or above, but newest phonegap have only 7.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

At times, you need to specify the version which you want to install. Please execute the below commands in the same order. Also, [Cordova Android 8.1.0](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/09/17/cordova-android-release-8.1.0.html) is the latest!

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@8.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your **config.xml**

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value='cli-9.0.0' />
```

The baove code is can be used if you are using Phonegap Build as well.